# Positive Number to Negative Number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math

Basically, the reverse of abs. If I have:

```
if ($this.find('.pdxslide-activeSlide').index() < slideNum - 1) {
  slideNum = -slideNum
}
console.log(slideNum)
```

No matter what console always returns a positive number. How do I fix this?

If I do:

```
if ($this.find('.pdxslide-activeSlide').index() < slideNum - 1) {
  _selector.animate({
    left: (-slideNum * sizes.images.width) + 'px'
  }, 750, 'InOutPDX')
} else {
  _selector.animate({
    left: (slideNum * sizes.images.width) + 'px'
  }, 750, 'InOutPDX')
}
```

it works tho, but it's not "DRY" and just stupid to have an entire block of code JUST for a `-`.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

```
Math.abs(num) => Always positive
-Math.abs(num) => Always negative
```

**You do realize, however, that for your code:**

```js
if($this.find('.pdxslide-activeSlide').index() < slideNum-1) {
   slideNum = -slideNum;
}

console.log(slideNum)
```

If the index found is 3 and slideNum is 3,
then `3 < 3-1 => false`
so slideNum **remains positive**??

It looks more like a logic error to me.

Answer (score 117):

The reverse of abs is `Math.abs(num) * -1`.

Comment: Shorter:
`return -Math.abs(num);`

Comment: this always return negative value, it wont change sign if num is negative.

Comment: how is this upvoted?

Comment: This is perfect if we want nagatives to remain negatives.

Answer (score 42):

The basic formula to reverse positive to negative or negative to positive:

```
i - (i * 2)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `i * -1`? Also, I'm not sure this answers the actual question.

Comment: It's architecturally dependant, but 0 - i might be faster

Comment: @AndrewBarber  `i * -1` does not seem to work in the current version of chrome. Use -Math.abs(1) not sure why this works though, hopefully someone can expand on the why.

Comment: @PhilipRollins `i * -1` will work, always. i don't know how you tried, maybe you had some typo. But... what's wrong with `i = -i` instead of `i = i * -1` (or  `i *= -1`) to reverse positive to negative or negative to positive?

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy I thought so too, but not for the version of chrome I was running and it worked in firefox so a typo is out of the question. I'm on Linux right now, but you're free to test your theory on chrome. Keep in mind chrome auto-updates so any bug fixes would already be applied and any new bugs would be pushed out to the community, meaning this could of been a bug that only lasted a few days and now is forever fixed.

Comment: @PhilipRollins it really seems to be a bug, because it is just math between two numbers, and nothing else.

Answer (score 24):

Javascript has a dedicated operator for this: [unary negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_negation).

TL;DR: It's the minus sign!

To negate a number, simply prefix it with `-` in the most intuitive possible way. No need to write a function, use `Math.abs()` multiply by `-1` or use the bitwise operator.

Unary negation works on number literals:

```
let a = 10;  // a is `10`
let b = -10; // b is `-10`
```

It works with variables too:

```
let x = 50;
x = -x;      // x is now `-50`

let y = -6;
y = -y;      // y is now `6`
```

You can even use it multiple times if you use the grouping operator (a.k.a. parentheses:

```
l = 10;       // l is `10`
m = -10;      // m is `-10`
n = -(10);    // n is `-10`
o = -(-(10)); // o is `10`
p = -(-10);   // p is `10` (double negative makes a positive)
```

All of the above works with a variable as well.

Comment: I think the author wanted the reverse of abs.

Answer (score 12):

To get a negative version of a number in JavaScript you can always use the `~` bitwise operator.

For example, if you have `a = 1000` and you need to convert it to a negative, you could do the following:

```
a = ~a + 1;
```

Which would result in `a` being `-1000`.

Comment: Is this faster than multiplying by negative 1?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest, something you'd have to look into.

Comment: @RyanDawkins this will not be faster than multiplying by -1. Javascript does not have boolean operators natively the way C does. So, to do a boolean operation, JS has to convert between types under the hood.

Comment: Why not `a = -a` ?

Comment: Bitwise does not negate a number exactly. `~1000` is `-1001`, not `-1000`.

Comment: But that's the reason that you add 1 to it. Also of note, is that this will also convert a negative number to positive

Answer (score 10):

```
num * -1
```

This would do it for you.

Answer (score 8):

```
var x = 100;
var negX = ( -x ); // => -100
```

Comment: Please add somes explanations editing your answer, avoid code only answer

Comment: @GGO ... I'm not sure how this is not clear already, but sure:
By adding the minus sign in front of the value, then wrapping that in parenthesis, the value is evaluated... the result is Negation of the value.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure that control is going into the body of the `if`? As in does the condition in the `if` ever hold true? Because if it doesn't, the body of the `if` will never get executed and `slideNum` will remain positive. I'm going to hazard a guess that this is probably what you're seeing.

If I try the following in Firebug, it seems to work:

```
>>> i = 5; console.log(i); i = -i; console.log(i);
5
-5
```

`slideNum *= -1` should also work. As should `Math.abs(slideNum) * -1`.

Comment: I just did `if($this.find('.pdxslide-activeSlide').index() < slideNum-1){ slideNum *= -1 }` and im still returning positive in that console.log?

Comment: @Oscar, what Vivin is saying is that `$this.find('.pdxslide-activeSlide').index() < slideNum-1` is always false.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't feel like using Math.Abs * -1 you can you this simple if statement :P

```
if (x > 0) {
    x = -x;
}
```

Of course you could make this a function like this

```
function makeNegative(number) {
    if (number > 0) {
        number = -number;
    }
}
```

makeNegative(-3) => -3
makeNegative(5) => -5

Hope this helps! Math.abs will likely work for you but if it doesn't this little

Comment: Before answering a question you should also consider when it was asked. This question is almost 5 years old. So unless technology has changed and there is now a better / more appropriate answer there is usually not much value added by offering another answer.

Comment: I personally look through old stack overflow questions all the time. Sure this won't be too helpful to a pro but perhaps a beginner might appreciate the tip! That said the easiest way really is as above 

-Math.Abs(-3)

As discussed above Math.Abs turns any value positive. Then the negative prefix makes it negative

Comment: Upvoted. Personally I appreciate this answer and found it valuable. You can learn from anyone.

Answer (score 4):

```
var i = 10;
i = i / -1;
```

Result: `-10`

```
var i = -10;
i = i / -1;
```

Result: `10`

If you divide by negative 1, it will always flip your number either way.

Answer (score 3):

Use 0 - x

x being the number you want to invert

Comment: just `-x` suffices.

Comment: Just -x results in -0. This solution is better if there might be zeros-

Answer (score 1):

It will convert negative array to positive or vice versa

```
function negateOrPositive(arr) {
    arr.map(res => -res)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla javascript

```js
if(number > 0)
  return -1*number;
```

Where **number** above is the positive number you intend to convert

This code will convert just positive numbers to negative numbers simple by multiplying by -1