# jquery math flip pos to neg and neg to pos

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

i need to convert numbers from negative to positive and positive to negative. I have tried the below but it only converts positive to negative. If a negative value comes through it stays negative. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        // Dials
        g1.refresh(Math.abs(data[0]) * -1);
        g2.refresh(data[1]);
        g3.refresh(data[2]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positive Number to Negative Number in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574144/positive-number-to-negative-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

`Math.abs(data[0])` is always postive, multiplying with `-1` will thus always have a negative result.

Use

```
g1.refresh(-data[0])
```

to flip the signum.