# Javascript: Changing a positive number to a negative?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to do the following - change a positive to a negative number.

It appears there are a number of ways to do this. There is the standard

```
x *= -1
```

or just placing a negative sign in front the variable i.e if x = 5, then -x is equal to -5.

This seems a great shorthand but wanted to know what the difference is, I can't find any documentation regarding this shorthand on MDN.

I assume there are other ways too.

Probably a basic question but it is annoying not understanding this apparent shorthand.

Any ideas ?

Comment: this will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574144/positive-number-to-negative-number-in-javascript

Comment: The "shorthand" [unary `-` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation_(-)) has to work otherwise how would you change `1` to `-1` in order to use the `*= -1` option? (As an aside, note that both `-` and `*` try to convert their operands to numbers, so `x *= "-1"` works, as does `x = "12"; x = -x;`.)

Comment: Added some more details below @martin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unary operators in Javascript are basically shorthand functions. You can find the documentation for the `Unary (-)` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation)

The `-` takes in one argument. The number you pass to it. Under the hood, I'm guessing it multiplies it by `-1` and returns the product. The function could be written along the lines of:

```
function -(arg) {
  return arg * -1;
}
```

This is conjecture though. Will need to go through V8's codebase to know for sure.

**Update:**

So from further research I figure that it's instead of multiplication by `-1`, it could be a simple sign change. I referred to V8's implementation but that proved to be a dead end because I suck at C++, but upon checking [ECMA's specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7) and the [IEEE 754 specs](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) defined here in Steve Hollasch's wonderful blog, I am leaning towards a inversion of the sign bit. All Javascript numbers are 64 Bit IEEE 754 FLoating Points, they can be represented like so:

```
SEEEEEEE EEEEMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM MMMMMMMM
```

Where `S` is the sign bit. So it looks like the Unary `-` just flips the sign bit.